# Retrieving the start position of an input split in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I have as a project to develop a simple document index using MapReduce in Hadoop. I need to retrieve the start position (as in byte offset from the beginning of the file) of the `FileSplit` that the `map()` function is currently working on. As far as I understand, the input split given to the `Mapper` is logically split into parts by a `RecordReader`, each of which is later `map()`-ed.

I read the [FileSplit](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileSplit.html) documentation and I tried doing:

```
((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getStart()
```

, but this always returns 0. Also, I am sure that the files are split in more than one part as I did some printing, so I expected non-zero values here and there.

Has someone else run in the same problem? I should also mention that I have little experience in Hadoop.

**Edit:**

There are 6 input files, each around 16KB (8KB compressed). All files seem to be split into two (`Map input records=12`). Each `Mapper` has its `map()` called twice, but both times `getStart()` returns 0.

Comment: Can you please add your debug prints? e.g. what file, it's size, how many splits, offset + length?

Comment: When you use a `FileSplit`, you should have 6 mappers for 6 input files, why do you think it is split into two? How does this relate to the map input records? Please show your code (job submission + mapper code).